# SIGABRT when using realloc()

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am attempting to make a C version of the game Snake for my homework assignment. I have implemented all the necesary mechainsms to the game but I'm having a problem with dynamic memory allocation. My 'snake' is stored in an array as a list of body pieces and their location. If the snake eats the fruit, I attempt to change the length of the snake and add another body piece to the array. Since I don't know the final size of the snake in advance I try to lengthen the array using realloc. Below is my code. Note: it works for 14 iterations before causing a SIGABRT.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void moveSnake(int *snakeLength,int direction, int **tableSnake, int extend);
int checkItems(int **tableSnake, int **items, int itemsSize);
int selfdestruct(int **tableSnake);

/* TEST INPUT DATA: 
9
-5 4 2
-3 4 1
-2 4 1
0 4 2
1 3 3
-2 2 1
0 2 1
-7 1 1
-5 1 3
15
*/

int main() {
    int xHead = 0;
    int yHead = 0;
    int snakeLength = 1;
    int direction = 1;

    // creates the snake table


    int **tableSnake;
    tableSnake = (int **) calloc(1,1 * sizeof (int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        tableSnake[i] = (int *) calloc(3,3 * sizeof (int));
    }

    tableSnake[0][0] = 0;
    tableSnake[0][1] = 0;
    tableSnake[0][2] = 1;


    // reads all the variables
    int noItems;
    scanf("%d", &noItems);

    int **items;
    items = (int **) malloc(noItems * sizeof (int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < noItems; i++) {
        items[i] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < noItems; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &items[i][0]);
        scanf("%d", &items[i][1]);
        scanf("%d", &items[i][2]);
    }


    int noSteps;
    scanf("%d", &noSteps);

    // start of run

    /*
     *  legend:
     *  direction: 1 - up, 2 - down, 3 - left, 4 - right
     *  typesOfItems: 5 - fruit, 6 - turn left, 7 - turn right 
     */

    int itemHead = 0;
    int extend = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < noSteps; i++) {
        moveSnake(&snakeLength,direction,tableSnake,extend);
        extend = 0;
        itemHead = checkItems(tableSnake, items, noItems);

        if(itemHead == -1){
            if(selfdestruct(tableSnake) == 1){
                snakeLength = 0;
                break;
            };
        }
        if (itemHead == 1) {
            extend = 1;
        } else if (itemHead == 2) {
            if(direction == 1){
                direction = 3;
            }else if(direction == 2){
                direction = 4;
            }else if(direction = 3){
                direction = 2;
            }else{
                direction = 1;
            }
        } else if (itemHead == 3) {
            if(direction == 1){
                direction = 4;
            }else if(direction == 2){
                direction = 3;
            }else if(direction = 3){
                direction = 1;
            }else{
                direction = 2;
            }
        } 
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", snakeLength, tableSnake[0][0], tableSnake[0][1]);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void moveSnake(int *snakeLength,int direction, int **tableSnake, int extend){
    int tempX = tableSnake[0][0];
    int tempY = tableSnake[0][1];
    int tempDirection = tableSnake[0][2];

    int tempXTail = tableSnake[*snakeLength -1][0];
    int tempYTail = tableSnake[*snakeLength -1][1];
    int tempDirectionTail = tableSnake[*snakeLength -1][2];

    int tempRep[3] = {tempXTail,tempYTail,tempDirectionTail};
    if(direction == 1){
        tempY++;
    }else if(direction == 2){
        tempY--;
    }else if(direction == 3){
        tempX--;
    }else if(direction == 4){
        tempX++;
    }

    int *temp;
    temp = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < *snakeLength; i++){
        temp = tableSnake[i];
        tableSnake[i][0] = tempX;
        tableSnake[i][1] = tempY;
        tableSnake[i][2] = tempDirection;
        tempX = temp[0];
        tempY = temp[1];
        tempDirection = temp[2];
    }
    if(extend == 1){
        // this is where the error occurs
        *snakeLength = *snakeLength +1;
        tableSnake = realloc(tableSnake, *snakeLength * sizeof(int));
        tableSnake[*snakeLength-1] = tempRep;
    }

}

int checkItems(int **tableSnake, int **items, int itemsSize){
    int *item;
    item = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    int itemX;
    int itemY;
    int headX = tableSnake[0][0];
    int headY = tableSnake[0][1];

    for(int i = 0; i < itemsSize; i++){
        item = items[i];
        itemX = item[0];
        itemY = item[1];
        if(itemX == headX && itemY == headY){
            return item[2];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int selfdestruct(int **tableSnake){
    int tempX = tableSnake[0][0];
    int tempY = tableSnake[0][1];
    int lengthTable = sizeof(tableSnake)/sizeof(tableSnake[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < lengthTable; i++){
        if(tempX == tableSnake[i][0]){
            if(tempY == tableSnake[i][1]){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you've got some memory leaks: `item = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: other issue: `temp = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < *snakeLength; i++){
        temp = tableSnake[i];
        tableSnake[i][0] = tempX;
        tableSnake[i][1] = tempY;
        tableSnake[i][2] = tempDirection;
        tempX = temp[0];
        tempY = temp[1];
        tempDirection = temp[2];
    }`  contents of `temp` is globally uninitialized the first time.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That would be the simple solution but my homework instructions state that the playing field should be the size 2.000.000x2.000.000 which is far too big to fit into memory

Answer (score 0):

If I put these two lines together, one problem should be obvious?

```
tableSnake = (int **) calloc(1,1 * sizeof (int *));
```

...

```
tableSnake = realloc(tableSnake, *snakeLength * sizeof(int));
```

and then you're not allocating memory for the new tableSnake element, but instead pointing it at a local variable...

```
tableSnake[*snakeLength-1] = tempRep;
```

...which will get automatically freed when you exit that function.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of:

```
tableSnake = realloc(tableSnake, *snakeLength * sizeof(int));
```

..does not propagate outside the moveSnake() function.  One fix is to return 'tableSnake' as a result

```
    int ** moveSnake(int *snakeLength,int direction, int **tableSnake, int extend){
      ...
      return tablesnake;
    );

...

tableSnake=moveSnake(&snakeLength,direction,tableSnake,extend);
```

This issue would probably not even arisen if you had named the vars more clearly, eg 'localSnake' for the parameter.  Try very hard to not give more than one var the same name:)